# How to choose the optimal point to split a string depending on its content with PHP

Tags: php, html

We have pieced together the following code to split a string at every 14th character and place a hyphen should the split occur in the middle a word:

```
$_SESSION['projekt_name'] = str_split(get_field('projekt_name'),14);

foreach($_SESSION['projekt_name'] as $projekt_name_part){
    if(substr($projekt_name_part,-1)!==' ' && substr($projekt_name_part,0,1)!==' ' && $projekt_name_part !== end($_SESSION['projekt_name'])){
        $html_projekt_name .= '<span>'.$projekt_name_part.'-</span><br>';
    }elseif(substr($projekt_name_part,0,1)==' '){
        $html_projekt_name = substr($html_projekt_name,0,-12).'</span><br><span>'.substr($projekt_name_part,1).'</span><br>';
    }else{
        $html_projekt_name .= '<span>'.$projekt_name_part.'</span><br>';
    }//end if
} //end for each
```

Generally this works fine. For example:

```
Array ( [0] => BURGERISTA my [1] => salad Plus Cit [2] => y)
```

gets rearranged as:

```
<span>BURGERISTA my </span><br><span>salad Plus Cit-</span><br><span>y</span>
```

But sometimes the split occurs too close to the beginning of a word. For example:

```
Array ( [0] => voestalpine Ti [1] => egelleitstand)
```

gets rearranged as:

```
<span>voestalpine Ti-</span>
<br>
<span>egelleitstand</span>
```

Ideally, this should get rearranged either as:

```
<span>voestalpine Tie-</span>
<br>
<span>gelleitstand</span>
```

or as:

```
<span>voestalpine</span>
<br>
<span>Tiegelleitstan-</span>
<br>
<span>d</span>
```

How do we make the split occur so that words don't get split too close to the beginning (ie. a minimum of 3 characters before the split occurs)?

Thanks in advance for any help!

Comment: http://www.tug.org/docs/liang/ (implemented in hunspell)